# Is it possible to have a Windows 8 Simulator conditional?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, simulator

I'm hitting getting a strange exception in my Windows 8 app when I try and run it the Simulator and try and Request Background Excution privelege using         `BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();`

I get

> "WinRT information: You can’t change background task and lock screen
>   privileges while running this app in the simulator."

This is obviously down to some issue due in how the Simulator works over RDP.

My question is, is there any way I can put a conditional around the offending line to avoid calling it when run in the simulator?

Comment: What sort of conditional exactly?  Why don't you just catch the exception and log it?  **This way your application won't crash because of an unhandled exception**

Comment: Actually that's probably good enough in this instance. I just want to avoid crashing the app when run in the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a conditional compilation symbol that you set when you want to run in the simulator.